# MySQL Cache every SELECT query until there is a new row?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, caching

I was thinking of using MySQL cache for a wordpress website, but it would cause issues on some sections such as admin and user area.

Is there any way we can configure all SELECT queries for every table to be cached "UNTIL" there is a new row in that table? in which the cache for that table is cleared.

Comment: I think you may be slightly confused about how a cache works.  The purpose of the cache is to buffer queries which happen often, thus reducing the number of hits that make it to the actual MySQL database.  The trigger to remove an item from the cache is not necessarily that a new record gets inserted, assuming that no one is querying for that new record.

Comment: Mysql's own query cache sort of works this way, if configured. But as @TimBiegeleisen has already pointed out, this is not the most efficient use.